# Enzyme can't find React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am testing some React components with enzyme, but I can not find a specific component inside the "wrapper component" that I am testing.

I have tried to do this like [this link](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/selector.md) is teaching, but it does not work.

This is my code:

**Todo.js**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from "react";
import TodoText from "./../containers/todo-text"

class Todo extends React.Component{
  (...)

  render(){

    return(
     <li className={todoClasses}>
      (...)
      <TodoText todoId={this.props.todoId} text={this.props.text} />
      (...)
     </li>
    );
  }

};

export default Todo;
```

**Todo-test.js**

```
import expect from 'expect';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Todo from '../path-to/todo.js';
import TodoText from '../path-to/todo-text.js';

function setup() {
  const props = {(...)};

  const enzymeWrapper =  shallow(<Todo {...props} />);

  return {
    props,
    enzymeWrapper
  }
}

describe('components', () => {
  describe('Todo', () => {
    it('should render self and subelements', () => {
      const { enzymeWrapper, props } = setup();

      (...)
      expect(enzymeWrapper.find(TodoText).length).toBe(1);
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Is ''//' a typo  in import Todo from '..//path-to/todo.js';?

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja yes, it is, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to access the child component you need to use mount and what you uses is Shallow and which is specifically for unit testing